# iOS app that can install files

Tags: ios, installation, cydia

Is it possible to make an iOS application and let it install files when you press a button? I think some Cydia apps do this but I can't seem to find any tutorials

Answer (score -1):

When you say "install files," what type of files are you talking about? Are you looking to install other apps, download pictures to the user's pictures folder, or something else?

It is not possible to copy files into another application's directory. If the other application supports opening certain document types with the "Open With" menu, the iPad will copy the file into the application's Inbox directory, but no other mechanism exists.

Comment: I'm trying to add files to another application, not really download an app but add files to one

Comment: Is there a way to add it to the downloads folder or pictures?